# Rails 3 - Application error, Rails application failed to start properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, dispatch

I would like to ask you for help about this error. I tried to search the solution, but unfortunately, still without success.

My directories have the right permission.

### dispatch.fcgi

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby1.8

#!/usr/local/bin/ruby

# You may specify the path to the FastCGI crash log (a log of unhandled
# exceptions which forced the FastCGI instance to exit, great for debugging)
# and the number of requests to process before running garbage collection.
#
# By default, the FastCGI crash log is RAILS_ROOT/log/fastcgi.crash.log
# and the GC period is nil (turned off).  A reasonable number of requests
# could range from 10-100 depending on the memory footprint of your app.
#
# Example:
#   # Default log path, normal GC behavior.
#   RailsFCGIHandler.process!
#
#   # Default log path, 50 requests between GC.
#   RailsFCGIHandler.process! nil, 50
#
#   # Custom log path, normal GC behavior.
   RailsFCGIHandler.process! '/log/myapp_fcgi_crash.log'
#
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../config/environment"
require 'fcgi_handler'

RailsFCGIHandler.process!
```

But in dir /log/myapp_fcgi_crash.log is empty log (in this directory I have **development.log** and **production.log** too).

I tried to set up **convig.enviroments.rb**

```
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the rails application
MexoApp::Application.initialize!

ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'production'
```

but unfortunately still is not working and still getting the error as is in title of this topic...

Can someone help me, please, how to fix this problem? I am struggling with this problem already second day and still no change...

Comment: It is on server hosting (linux).

Comment: If work least a logging of errors, will it be a bit easier...

Comment: OK, what is the output of each of the following commands: "ruby -v", "gem -v", and "rails -v"?

Comment: I have not the access through SSL to server. But I sent gems of my application to my provider and he installed them. So in this should't be the problem. Ruby is in version 1.8, Rails in version 3

Comment: Please do not use FCGI to set up your Rails application. There are *much* better solutions such as Passenger, Unicorn or even a Mongrel cluster.

Comment: What's in your `production.log`?